# matplotlib draws line through whole figure every time I try to change window dimension

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The goal is to output real time data on graph with ability to change it dimensions. I'm trying to work with default matplotlib example taken from [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/animation/animate_decay.html). I've changed it just a little:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def data_gen():
    t = data_gen.t
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 10000:
        cnt+=1
        t += 0.05
        yield t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(-t/40.)
data_gen.t = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.grid()
xdata, ydata = [], []
def run(data):
    t,y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    if t >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,run,data_gen,blit=True,interval=10,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Everything is fine until the window dimension is changed. Matplotlib draws line to first point through whole figure and then another line to point where it suppose to be. Finally it looks like [this](https://hsto.org/files/ffa/62c/e4b/ffa62ce4bcb3439ea3cec9334c3b10f1.png). So the figure is messed up, and I don't know what to do with it.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, python 2.7.9, matplotlib 1.4.3. Same happens on Windows 7 and 8.1.

Comment: By "change window dimension", do you mean by dragging the window border with the mouse?  Are you doing that while the animation is running?

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, exactly.

Comment: For me, it works if I use `blit=False`.  I got the idea from [this bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4901), although it doesn't seem directly related.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah, it works excellent. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question completely and since this issue appears even in matplotlib 2.0.0, I will answer this question myself. As **@BrenBarn** pointed out, all I need is just `blit=False`.